# MySQL: Select rows above

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to write a MySQL query that selects all items that are one row up from those that match certain criteria?

For example, to get the prices where 'Valuation' is greater than 5:

```
SELECT  Price  FROM  table  WHERE   Valuation > 5
```

But how would you go about getting the price the day *after* the valuation rose above 5?

```
Date        Price   Valuation
01/06/2016    9.2       9
31/05/2016    9.3       5
27/05/2016    9.5       8
26/05/2016    9.7       7
25/05/2016    9.5       8
24/05/2016    9.3       4
23/05/2016    9.2       3
20/05/2016    9.2       5
19/05/2016    8.9       9
18/05/2016    9.1       4
17/05/2016    9.2       9
```

In this example, it would be 9.3, 9.5, 9.7, 9.2 and 9.1

**edit:** an index column could be added to the table if that would help.

**edit:** by "one day later" I meant the next row up in the table (rather than the next day chronologically)

Comment: Not easily. MySQL does not have built-in support for row-number'ish and other view functions. There are workabouts. In any case, the first step is to establish a dense ordering, then join on prev+next rows (based on the ordering), and then choose only those joined records that meet the condition. For smaller datasets a *dependent subquery* would also work suitably.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Assuming an index key column was added, would that help?

Comment: The first/next must be deterministic, such that it can be a join `on a.row_rn = b.row_rn + 1` or similar. A dependant subquery doesn't have this requirement as one can use `min\max` with a `where` filter inside.

Comment: Which one is the *day after the valuation rose above 5*?

Comment: An index column might help, I don't think that it is necessary (see my answer in a minute)

Comment: Valuation field reaches a value of `5` twice in your dataset: on `31/05/2016` and on `20/05/2016`. Your query should then return the records of `01/06/2016` and `21/05/2016`, so a total of 2 records. I don't get why you expect to get 5 records.

Comment: @Jocelyn: same problem here as well; Ned, could you enrich your example with the dates?

Comment: @EagleRainbow When the value is greater than five

Comment: @Jocelyn When the value is greater than five (not when it equals five)

Comment: @Ned Do you mean exactly one day later or the subsequent row in the table?

Comment: @shawnt00 I meant the subsequent row in the table. Sorry for not specifying that.

Comment: The difficulty is in writing the question up, with expected results. That is often more difficult than performing the sql

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that we have

```
CREATE TABLE quotes( 
  `date` date not null primary key,
  price numeric(5,1) not null,
  valuation integer not null
);


INSERT INTO quotes VALUES
('2016-06-01', 9.2, 9),
('2016-05-31', 9.3, 5),
('2016-05-27', 9.5, 8),
('2016-05-26', 9.7, 7),
('2016-05-25', 9.5, 8),
('2016-05-24', 9.3, 4),
('2016-05-23', 9.2, 3),
('2016-05-20', 9.2, 5),
('2016-05-19', 8.9, 9),
('2016-05-18', 9.1, 4),
('2016-05-17', 9.2, 9);
```

Then the following `SELECT`statement does the trick:

```
SELECT basedate, quotes.*
FROM 
(
    SELECT basedate, min(date) AS nextDate
    FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT date as basedate FROM quotes WHERE Valuation > 5) as dates
        LEFT JOIN quotes ON dates.basedate < quotes.date
    ) as aggrtable
    GROUP BY basedate
) as fullTable
LEFT JOIN quotes ON fullTable.nextDate = quotes.date;
```

Let's check this one from inner to outer:

- The innerst `SELECT` statement retrieves the quotes, which are of interested at all `VALUATION > 5`. Those dates, where the condition holds true, are called `basedate` here.
- The next layer does a non-equi join to the table itself, determining all possible dates "after" our base dates.
- The alias `aggrtable` the determines the dates, which are "after" the base date, but stays closest to the base date (using the `min` aggregation function).
- To finally retrieve the values from the `quotes` again, the result is joined with the original table again, making the join condition on the "minimal closest date" of the base date.

NB: This non-equi join in between may become ugly on large tables: Let's assume that we have dates of several dozens of years in the database. On the second day the valuation went above 5. Then this non-equi join will generate all dates in the result except  the first two. Thus, if you have bad luck, this may lead to `O(n²)` records, which need to be generated temporarily, but then are condensed again by the aggregation over `min`. Thus, your result set will only have `O(n)` records at maximum, but may need `O(n²)` time/space. You may also cross-check this discussion by using the `EXPLAIN` statement; there you will find an `EXTRA = "Using temporary, Using filesort"` which is something very evil in regards of performance.

Comment: This query looks for dates where the valuation was already greater than 5 but it doesn't find the transition.

Comment: @shawnt00 That's exactly that, what is being requested in the question: "each `VALUATION > 5`" irrespectively of triggering mechanism. Furthermore, the question also confirms this assumption when looking at the example: `9.3, 9.5, 9.7, 9.2` and `9.1` (not saying that I would understand where to use that :) )

Comment: It says *rose above*. I read that as a transition from below. Obviously it needs some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If just want to find date/price/valuation immediately following any date where the valuation was above five, regardless of the valuation in days preceeding it use this:

```
select * from T
where Date in (
    select min(t2.Date)
    from T t1 inner join T t2 on t2.Date > t1.Date
    where t1.Valuation > 5
    group by t1.Date
)
```

*Explanation*: Look for days where the valuation is above 5. In each instance do a self join to find all dates later and keep only the earliest one found. Now return all data for that list of dates. The self join will be faster if you can give it an upper bound like never having to look more than a week.

If you're looking for transitions in valuations it's more complicated:

```
select * from T
where `Date` in (
    select t2.`Date`
    from T t1 inner join T t2
        on      t2.`Date` > t1.`Date`
            and t2.`Date` < date_add(t1.`Date`, interval 7 day) /* bound for performance */
    where
        /* valuation starts at or below 5 */
        t1.Valuation <= 5

        /* did we find the day after the next day? */
        and 3 = (
            select count(*) from T t3
            where t3.`Date` between t1.`Date` and t2.`Date`
        )

        /* did the valuation rise above 5 on the day in between */
        and 5 < (
            select t4.Valuation from T t4
            where t4.`Date` > t1.`Date` and t4.`Date` < t2.`Date`
        )
)
```

By *rose above* I first believed you were looking for a transition from below five to above five. Then you wanted the price on the day subsequent to that one. This interpretation doesn't not seem to match your sample data though.

Here's a place to test the queries on SQL Server. http://rextester.com/BQFJDE14701

Comment: returns a single "null", "null", "null" record  here for me on my testset (same data as above)

Comment: @EagleRainbow I was just going to work on testing it. But I don't see how you could get any kind of null results with the filters in the query.

Comment: use it on top of: 
create table quotes( 
  `date` date not null primary key,
  price numeric(5,1) not null,
  valuation integer not null
);
  
  
insert into quotes values
('2016-06-01', 9.2, 9),
('2016-05-31', 9.3, 5),
('2016-05-27', 9.5, 8),
('2016-05-26', 9.7, 7),
('2016-05-25', 9.5, 8),
('2016-05-24', 9.3, 4),
('2016-05-23', 9.2, 3),
('2016-05-20', 9.2, 5),
('2016-05-19', 8.9, 9),
('2016-05-18', 9.1, 4),
('2016-05-17', 9.2, 9);

Comment: @EagleRainbow My mistake was in using the wrong column for the greater/less than 5 tests.

Comment: mmmh.. your updated version still only returns three of the five records... the dates returned are: 2016-06-01, 2016-05-25, 2016-05-19

Answer (score 0):

You basically want the previous valuation.  One method uses variables and another uses a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*,
      (select p2.valuation
       from prices p2
       where p2.date < p.date
       order by p2.date desc
       limit 1
      ) as prev_valuation
from prices p;
```

Now you just want to add the condition at the previous valuation is greater than 5.  MySQL let's you do this with a `having` clause:

```
select p.*,
      (select p2.valuation
       from prices p2
       where p2.date < p.date
       order by p2.date desc
       limit 1
      ) as prev_valuation
from prices p
having prev_valuation > 5;
```